# Order In Layer and on Sorting Group don't work well

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added Sorting Group to diferent objects, and run very well, but I have a lot of problems with a fences ( look the picture ), I tried to add Sorting Group but didn't run well, so I tried modify Order in Layer with a script and I have the same problem, the other way that I tried are put manualy order in layer, and only run in front or background.

I passed a lot of hours thinking about this and test diferent things and I don't know what is the problem and solution.

I need help from the comunity to learn about this problem, probably the problem is the sprite I don't know, i'm really confused and disturbed.

Script is very simple and ineficient (only to test):
SpriteRenderer [] rendererFernce;

```
void Awake()    
{    
     rendererFernce = FindObjectsOfType<SpriteRenderer>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
     foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in rendererFernce)
     {
          renderer.sortingOrder = (int)(renderer.transform.position.y * -100);
     }
}
```

[Wrong Order in Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6VlB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have different causes.

1. the fence is actually a 3d model: 3d models are shown on top of sprites if they are closer to the camera.
2. the center of the transforms are not where you think they are: the fence is very wide and different parts of it have different positions on the y 'axis'
3. you are changing the orderInLayer but not the sorting layers: layers have priority over orderInLayer

You can try to change this setting and see if it works instead of implementing it yourself:
Edit > Projecting Settings > Graphics > Transparency Sort Axis
setting it to (0, 1, 0)

You can find more information related to sorting [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Originaly fences are 3D model but I convert to 2D models to use in my project. It's true that they are very wide, I corrected my problem dividing the fence in diferent parts, this solve my problem but I think is not the better solution, I'm sure thtat I do anything very bad.

But, currently works well, thank you a lot for the solution.